# What is the difference between two method of calling javascript method

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning JavaScript and trying to understand it. It may be very simple for you but I do need the explanation. So here is my code of java script file.

```
function divClick(){
alert("Hello World!!!");
}
```

So if I Call it like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").click(function(){
    divClick();
});});
```

Everything is working fine and alert box is appearing only when I click on div element. but If I access it like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").click(divClick());});
```

The alert box is appearing automatically as soon as page load. I am really not able to understand that, Could you please explain it. If there is any url I would be happy to learn it.

Comment: Please, before ever sharing code again, first learn how to do proper indentation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Comment: I am sorry I will take care of that next time. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like in many programming languages (Python, Java, C, C++, etc), when you have a function call like

```
foo(a, b, ...);
```

all the expressions `a`, `b`, etc. are evaluated first and then their result is passed to `foo` as arguments.

In case of

```
$("div").click(function(){
    divClick();
});
```

the expression, is `function(){ divClick(); }`, which is a *function expression*. The result of evaluating it is a *function (object)*. Hence a function is passed to `.click`.

In the case of

```
$("div").click(divClick());
```

the expression is `divClick()`, which is a *function call*. That means the function `divClick` is *executed* and whatever it returns is passed to `.click`.

---

Simplified example:

```
function a(arg) {
    alert(arg);
}

function b() {
    return 42;
}

a(b()); // alerts 42
```

Here `b` is executed first, its return value is `42`. This value is passed as argument to `a` and accessible within the function as `arg`.

---

> If there is any url I would be happy to learn it.

There really isn't anything special about it. It's how function calls are evaluated. Maybe you get confused by the function which is passed as *argument*. In JavaScript, functions are first-class citizens and can be passed around like any other value (numbers, booleans, strings, ...).

Reading material about functions:

- http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Functions
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function

Comment: You are absolutely right, Thank you very much for the detail explaination.

Answer (score 2):

The second immediately calls `divClick()` and passes what it returns as a `.click()` callback handler.

Use this instead:

```
$("div").click(divClick);
```

here we're passing a reference to a function as an event handler.

Comment: Thank you very much, do you suggest me any good book or URL so that I can learn it.

Answer (score 0):

When you register an event, in this case `click`, the input is a reference to the function that should be invoked when the event happens. In the first case you are defining an anonymous function. However, in the second case, the `divClick()` is not the reference, so it evaluates and expects the function `divClick` to return a reference. During evaluation, your method actually gets invoked and hence the behavior.

Comment: @zerkms: Thanks, I rectified it.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing the answer of Felix Kling 
you can change

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div").click(divClick());
});
```

for

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div").click(divClick);
});
```

in that way you are passing a function object called "divClick" instead of the return value of "divClick()" in this case is nothing.

Other dirty form to work would be change the function for something like this

```
function divClick(){
   return function(){ 
      alert("Hello World!!!");
   }
}
```